# Question about passing data using intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to modify the Notepad tutorial (the Notepadv3 solution) to take in a value into the NoteEdit class, given to by the Notepadv3 class. I've successfully used .putExtra in the OnListItemClick method to place the value into the NoteEdit class, but I'm struggling to do this for the createNote method; I'm getting a force close when I try to create a new note.

I bet there's a simple solution, but I'm pretty new to Java & Android and would very much appreciate your help.

Here's the code in question in the Notepadv3 class:

```
private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra("key", 1);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra("key", 1);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
                                Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
```

And here's the receiving code in the NoteEdit class:

```
mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                        : null;
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                : null;
                    value = extras.getInt("key");

    }
```

I'm fairly sure that (mRowId == null) is not true when I'm using the createNote method so therefore getExtras won't be called. One of my questions would be how can I make my NoteEdit class get this value when I use the createNote method? I'm new to this so sorry if this is a simple question for you all.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Use adb logcat, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to view the Java stack trace associated with the "force close", to see where things are blowing up.

Comment: Yeah I've had a look at the logcat on the DDMS perspective, the one that seems to jump out at me is this:


04-19 14:40:05.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18951): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception



04-19 14:40:05.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listview/com.example.listview.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

So it's a cursor problem? I'm sure it's to do with (mRowId == null) not being true. Any thoughts?

Comment: `savedInstanceState` should be `null` when your activity is started via `startActivity()` (or `startActivityForResult()`, as is the case here). Hence, if you believe that `mRowId` is being set from `savedInstanceState` when you call `createNote()`, then there is something fairly seriously messed up somewhere.

Comment: Do you think I should try passing a different value or different variable name with .putExtra in OnCreate? (i.e. i.putExtra("keytwo", 1) Or am I understanding intents and extras wrong? Not sure how to proceed..

Comment: If you look at the error logs you should find it gives you the exact line number in your code with the problem. The line numbers are associated with each package, but you can be pretty sure the fault isn't with one of the OS's packages. So look for the first instance of yours, and then find the line number. In my SDK samples the package name for this one is com.android.demo.notepadv3, but you might have changed that.

Comment: Sorry, I've found the DDMS perspective but how do I find the error log? I'm not sure what it is I need to look at.

Comment: I've found the error log, but I'm not getting any errors appearing in that box, is there a log file I can open to view errors or something? Sorry for all the noobish questions, I'm trying to learn Java. Thank you so much for the help and advice so far.

Anyway, yeah, any idea how to view the error log that Steve H mentions?

Comment: check the logcat view (=click on the very buttom on the green droid to get logcat) then click on the red E and you will just be shown the errors. Also I would debug the code step by step and start with a breakpoint in line   mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                : null;
then check the value of extras. Is it null by any chance?

Comment: @Joe as commonsware says there is not enough information in your post to troubleshoot this. Please include a stack trace.

Comment: In order to see the logs, you need to exit the logcat view, and under devices, click your device. This will update the logs to that device itself.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `Intent` to start another activity, the receiving activity must use the `getIntent()` method to access it; there is no reason to use `savedInstanceState` for this purpose; that's only useful when "restoring" an activity's current state because it was interrupted.

You can use the "extras" of the `Intent` in the sending activity to transmit the data you want to send.  The receiving activity uses the same extra names to get to the data.  Also, never assume all the extras were sent (i.e. check for `null`s!)

You should make all the decisions about what the activity's action is, in the `onCreate` method of the receiving activity.

If an activity can be "started" multiple ways, you must use `Intent.setAction()` in the `Intent` and check for all valid actions, in the receiving activity.

Also, do not depend on the `id` parameter in `onListItemClick` it is often incorrect.  The `position` parameter is always correct, and you can use it to get to the actual item from the adapter, and get the ID from the item. Usually, one sets the `Intent`'s data URI instead of sending the ID as an extra; this works better with the system's Activity resolution (see below).

In fact, "data manipulation" activities should support the standard actions for data editing, `INSERT`, `EDIT` and the like, and have intent filters that specify those actions and your data's MIME type.  I'm pretty sure those are part of the example application.

In the receiving activity, you must call `Activity.setResult()`, and you typically send back return data (e.g. new content URL) via another `Intent`, which you then access from the sending activity in `onActivityResult()`.  Also, you must call `setResult()` at an appropriate time; e.g. calling it during lifecycle exit (`onPause()` or `onStop()`) is too late, and will not transmit your results back.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mRowId == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
    mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                            : null;
    if (mRowId == 0) mRowId = null;

    value = extras.getInt("key");

}
```

Modify the code like this. The problem is that calling createNote creates a new note with mRowId as null. However since you're passing the "key" argument the extras won't be null but neither will it have a value for KEY_ROWID and getLong() returns 0 as default. The problem emerges later when you're querying for _id = 0 in populateFields()